# Issues with jQuery sending value from PHP controller $this->input->post('id', TRUE);

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

view.php

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.buttons > a').livequery("click",function(e){
        var parent  = $(this).parent();
        var getID   =  parent.attr('id').replace('button_','');
        var url = '<?php echo site_url('cart/price');?>';
        $.post(url+"?id="+getID, {}, function(response){
            $('#button_'+getID).html($(response).fadeIn('slow'));
        });
    }); 
});

<span class="buttons" id="button_5"><a class="btn-following" href="javascript: void(0)"></a></span>
```

controller:

```
$gid = $this->input->post('id', TRUE);
$this->Product_model->following($gid);
```

model:

```
function following($gid){       
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tf_followers (following_id) VALUES('".$gid."')");        
}
```

from this I am getting empty value to database and this is correct way to pass value through jQuery.

Comment: if you want to pass variable that way just use $.post(url+"/"+getID, ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to properly pass data to `$.post`, use its 3 parameter overload:

```
$.post(url, {id: getID}, function(response){
    $('#button_'+getID).html($(response).fadeIn('slow'));
});
```

If you want to pass it with GET (like you were), you can't get it in the collection of POST variables on the server.